flutter Internationalising not generated for other languages
I'm currently working on implementing internationalization in a Flutter app. Initially, I successfully integrated English language support by generating an app_en.arb file, updating it, and then seeing the changes reflected in my app after the automatic generation of app_localizations_en.dart.
However, when attempting the same process with app_fr.arb for French language support, I encountered an issue. Despite following the same steps, I found that app_localizations_fr.dart wasn't generated. Consequently, this led to an error in the app;
"Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value
Another exception was thrown: Warning: This application's locale, fr, is not
supported by all of its localization delegation"
This is my config:
// Folder/lib/main.dart file
localizationsDelegates: const [
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: const [
          Locale('en'),
          Locale('fr'),
        ],
       locale:  Locale('fr'), // I switch to en then it works for "en"

// at Folder/l10n.yaml

arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart

// at Folder/pubspec.yaml

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: any
flutter:
  generate: true

// Folder/lib/l10n/app_en.arb => file
// Folder/lib/l10n/app_fr.arb => file


Generate localization files
flutter pub global run intl_utils:generate


Thanks but it does not solve the issue. Keep in mind that app_en.arb is generated when I update it. But somehow app_fr.arb is ignored. Thanks.

remove generated folder once and try to run above command.
